# Items is my component are not dispatched in an uniform way

Tags: css, flexbox

I am facing an issue with flexbox layout, where i don't manage to make the flow always regular as I add items.

Here a jsFiddle of the issue: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/loloof64/f6ovbt95/33/). (I don't know how to integrate into this post, I would like to do it). You just have to click on the button to add items.

Here is the html

```html
<my-app></my-app>
```

Here is the js

```js
let { Component, NgModule, NgOnInit } = ng.core;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="header"><button (click)="addItem()">Add item</button></div>
    <div class="history_main">
      <div *ngFor="let item of allItems" class="moveEntry"></div>
    </div>
  `,
})
class HomeComponent implements NgOnInit {
        allItems = [];
    itemsCount = 0;

    addItem() {
        this.allItems.push('a');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.itemsCount; i++) this.allItems.push('a');
    }
}

const { BrowserModule } = ng.platformBrowser;

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ HomeComponent ]
})
class AppModule { }

const { platformBrowserDynamic } = ng.platformBrowserDynamic;
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Here the css

```css
.history_main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: content;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: beige;
    align-items: flex-start;

    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.moveEntry {
    display: inline-box;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    background-color: red;

    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
}

.header {
  display: block;
}
```

What I would like is to keep the distance between two lines of items always the same, and not being reduced as I add more and more items.

I know it has something to do with flexbox properties, but I still don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix this by adding a wrapper around the `.history_main div` and let that div take care of the width and height of your app. Additionally, you don't need to add `display: inline-box;` to your `.moveEntry` div.

Updated CSS:

```css
.history_main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: content;
  overflow: scroll;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: beige;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.moveEntry {
  margin: 5px 10px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
}

.header {
  display: block;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/s4h7t6j8/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there also a way to prevent the history_main zone from growing also and making it scroll ? Because here overflow:scroll property does not seem to work anymore

Comment: Found how to fix it. I just need to set the overflow in the wrapper css. Thank you for having lead me in the right way. http://jsfiddle.net/loloof64/m7Lx2vs0/2/